# Create a random number between the max and min ID

Tags: sql-server, select, random

I need to create three random id between the max ID of the table and the min ID of the table. How can I do that in Sql?

Comment: what does *max ID* and *min ID* mean exactly? By any chance, Are you trying to retrieve 3 random rows from a table?

Comment: What have your attempted so far?

Comment: sorry if i didn't explain myself clearly. as id, I mean the primary key of the table. I would like to select three user randomly from the table without repetition the users. i tried the use SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sch.Referee
ORDER BY NEWID() but, i couldnt use it in while loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two variables to store Min and Max primary keys. let's say **`@a`** and **`@b`**.
then using below query you can get your random number

```
declare @a int,@b int
select @b=max(id),@a=min(id)
from  mytbl

SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(@b-@a)+1)
```